# Doctrine + Twig, How to display Doctrine collection in a OneToMany relationship with a limit?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, twig

I have a OneToMany Relationship with two entities :

One `Article` has a `Brand` and one `Brand` has many `Articles`.
How, in my Twig template, I can display only 5 `Articles` of each `Brand` ?

What is the best practise to do that with a light query ?

Below, my code :

```
{% for brand in colBrands %}

        {% for article in brand.articles %}

            <!-- Display only 5 results and stop -->

        {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) function:

```
{% for brand in colBrands %}

        {% for article in brand.articles|slice(0, 5) %}

            <!-- Display only 5 results and stop -->

        {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What about speed ? If I have more than 10000 rows ? Will it fetch all rows and show only 5 ?

Comment: Yes it will.  I would not recommend this approach in that scenario.